# Interdependent interfaces using generics in C#

Tags: generics, interface, c#-2.0

My apologies if it is quite confusing.

I have this two main interfaces. First the `ISensor` interface:

```
public interface ISensor<TReading>
    where TReading : ISensorReading<ISensor<TReading>>
{
    event SensorReadingCompletedEH<ISensor<TReading>, TReading> ReadCompleted;
    TReading Read();
}
```

And the second interface: `ISensorReading`:

```
public interface ISensorReading<TSensor>
    where TSensor : ISensor<ISensorReading<TSensor>>
{
    TSensor Sensor { get; }
}
```

It leads to the following errors:

*The type ISensor<TReading> must be convertible to

ISensor<ISensorReading<ISensor<TReading>>> in order to use it as parameter TSensor in the generic type or method ISensorReading<TSensor>*

and

*The type ISensorReading<TSensor> must be convertible to
 ISensorReading<ISensor<ISensorReading<TSensor>>> in order to use it as parameter TReading in the generic type or method ISensor<TReading>*

I fear it is due to an insolvable circular reference at compile time; however I want to ensure congruence for derived types like TelemetricSensor : `ISensor<TelemetricReading>` and 
TelemetricReading : `ISensorReading<TelemetricSensor>`

Which other aproaches should I use to allow simple casting and type safe?

I am using .NET 2.0 and VS2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your answers.

Finally this is the solution I choose for the problem. Hope to be usefull. If you have comments or know a way to impriove it without change the framework, let me know.

First I created an ISensor interface with the minimal requirements. After that I defined a new ISensor generic interface as follows:

```cs
public delegate void SensorErrorEventHandler<TSensor>(TSensor sensor, ISensorError error)
    where TSensor : ISensor;

public delegate void SensorReadingCompletedEventHandler<TSensor, TReading>(TSensor sensor, TReading[] read)
    where TSensor : ISensor
    where TReading : ISensorReading<TSensor>;

public interface ISensor : IDisposable
{
    bool IsOpen { get; }
    bool Started { get; }
    void Connect();
    void Disconnect();
    void Start();
    void Stop();
}

public interface ISensor<TSensor, TReading> : ISensor
    where TSensor : ISensor
    where TReading : ISensorReading<TSensor>
{
    TReading[] LastReadings { get; }
    event SensorErrorEventHandler<TSensor> Error;
    event SensorReadingCompletedEventHandler<TSensor, TReading> ReadCompleted;
    bool Read(out TReading[] readings);
}

public interface ISensorReading<TSensor> where TSensor : ISensor
{
    TSensor Sensor { get; }
    bool Mistaken { get; }
}
```

With theese interfaces defined and following the same structures, I was able to made the first implementation: A TelemetricSensor class with its correspondient ITelemetricReading

```cs
public delegate void TelemetricSensorThresholdExceededEventHandler<TSensor>(TSensor sensor)
    where TSensor : ITelemetricSensor;

public interface ITelemetricSensor : ISensor
{
    /* Properties, events and methods */
}

public interface ITelemetricReading : ISensorReading<ITelemetricSensor>
{
    /* Properties, events and methods */
}

public abstract class TelemetricSensor<TSensor, TReading> : ITelemetricSensor, ISensor<TSensor, TReading>
    where TSensor : ITelemetricSensor
    where TReading : ITelemetricReading, ISensorReading<TSensor>
{
    public abstract TReading[] LastReadings { get; }
    public event SensorErrorEventHandler<TSensor> Error;
    public event SensorReadingCompletedEventHandler<TSensor, TReading> ReadCompleted;

    public abstract bool Read(out TReading[] readings);
}
```

Here TReading of the TelemetricSensor abstract class is interesting. It is defined as

```cs
TReading : ITelemetricReading, ISensorReading<TSensor>
```

which may appear to be redundant because ITelemetricReading inherits from ISensorReading, but it is required to get the code compile and met the requirement for both

```cs
TReading[] LastReadings { get; }
```

property and

```cs
bool Read(out TReading[] readings);
```

method. Finally to skip tedious casting (and perhaps some errors) mutiple overloads of Read(...) can be done so each provides the data casted correctly and also met all interface implementations.

Answer (score 1):

You are right- you can't define them using generic type constraints this way, because it leads to infinite nesting.

What you can do is have a concrete implementation of one or the other, for instance:

```
public interface ITelemetricSensorReading : ISensorReading
```

and then constrain the sensor to enforce an implementation of that:

```
public interface ITelemetricSensor<TReading> : ISensor<TReading> where TReading : ITelemetricSensorReading
```

Answer (score 1):

Say, you define your two types:

```
    class AReading : ISensorReading<ASensor> { }
    class ASensor : ISensor<AReading> { }
```

Now, declaration `ISensorReading<ASensor>` is illegal, because `ASensor` does NOT implement `ISensor<ISensorReading<ASensor>>`. Instead, it implements `ISensor<Areading>`, which is different.

See, in .NET, the statement `A : B` does not generally imply statement `I<A> : I<B>`. And if you think about it carefully, this is not necessarily true - depends on the nature of `I`.

The feature(s) you're looking for are called "Covariance" and "Contravariance". That is another feature of C#, where you can tell the compiler that for your particular interface `I`, the above implication does, in fact, hold (covariance), or that the reverse implication `I<B> : I<A>` holds (contravariance).

The first one you achieve by using the `out` keyword:

```
    interface I<out T> { ... }
```

The second - by using the `in` keyword:

```
    interface I<in T> { ... }
```

Unfortunately, however, covariance and contravariance in generic type parameters has only been introduced in C# 4.0, so you're out of luck here.

You could upgrade to C# 4.0 (which is what I strongly recommend), or you could rely on your unit tests to make sure all types stay coherent.

Comment: Indeed some times covariance and contravariance causes headache.
Unfortunately my applications must be as compatible as possible with MONO and upgrade to C# 4.0 is not an option. Also I've noticed .NET 4.0 is not as eficient as .NET 2.0

Comment: .net 4.0 is less efficient than 2.0? How, exactly?